# JSON filter "smaller then" condition

Tags: python, json, filter

I have a JSON which looks like this:

```
{
    "data": [
    {
      "Name": "Hello",
      "Number": "20"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Beautiful",
      "Number": "22"
    },
    {
      "Name": "World",
      "Number": "25"
    },
    {
      "Name": "!",
      "Number": "28"
    }
}
```

and I want to get everything what is smaller than 28, it should look like this:

```
{
    "data": [
    {
      "Name": "Hello",
      "Number": "20"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Beautiful",
      "Number": "22"
    },
    {
      "Name": "World",
      "Number": "25"
    }
}
```

I looked for a solution but all I have found was to remove an exact value.
I'm doing this with a much larger file this is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

An example could use list comprehension:

```
data = {
    "data": [
    {
      "Name": "Hello",
      "Number": "20"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Beautiful",
      "Number": "22"
    },
    {
      "Name": "World",
      "Number": "25"
    },
    {
      "Name": "!",
      "Number": "28"
    }
  ]
}
filter_ = 28
filtered = { 
    "data": [
        item for item in data["data"] 
        if int(item["Number"]) < filter_
     ] 
}
print(filtered)
```

Basically, this creates iterates through data["data"], checks if that current item's number is less than the filter (28 in this case), and adds those to the list. You're left with:

```
{'data': [{'Name': 'Hello', 'Number': '20'}, {'Name': 'Beautiful', 'Number': '22'}, {'Name': 'World', 'Number': '25'}]}
```

...which should be what you need, but unformatted.

---

However, for larger JSON files, you might want to look into [ijson](https://pypi.org/project/ijson/#usage), which allows you to load json files in a memory-efficient way. Here's an example:

```
import ijson
import json

filter_ = 28
with open('data.json', 'r') as file:
  items = ijson.items(file, 'data.item')
  filtered = [item for item in items if int(item["Number"]) < filter_]
  with open('filtered.json', 'w') as output:
    json.dump(filtered, output, indent=2)
```

[Try this code online](https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/SarcasticProductiveFolder#main.py)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple for loop

```py
import json

with open('your_path_here.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for elem in data['data']:
    if int(elem['Number']) >= 28:
        data['data'].remove(elem)

print(data)
>>> {
    "data": [
    {
      "Name": "Hello",
      "Number": "20"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Beautiful",
      "Number": "22"
    },
    {
      "Name": "World",
      "Number": "25"
    }
}
```